# Why does the punishment of him who kills Cain seem more severe in Genesis 4:15:

Tags: genesis, niv, cain, abel

Genesis 4:10 NIV

10 The Lord said, “What have you done? Listen! Your brother’s blood cries out to me from the ground. 11 Now you are under a curse and driven from the ground, which opened its mouth to receive your brother’s blood from your hand. 12 ***When you work the ground, it will no longer yield its crops for you. You will be a restless wanderer on the earth***.”

The punishment of one who kills Cain seems more severe than Cain's punishment

Genesis 4:15 NIV

15 But the Lord said to him, “Not so[e]; ***anyone who kills Cain will suffer vengeance seven times*** over.” Then the Lord put a mark on Cain so that no one who found him would kill him.

Why does the punishment of him who kills Cain seem more severe?

Comment: (speculation, so a comment) ¶ Notice that the name "Cain" means "possession" and "Abel" means "vanity" or "vain" in Hebrew.
As first-born, Cain was the natural possessor of Adam's name and legacy, something that the vain Abel might have resented.
Then, seeing Cain being put down, the vain Abel might have gloated and provoked his already angry and embarrassed elder brother, resulting in the fatal response.
That wouldn't absolve Cain, but it *would* make it manslaughter. And any later killing of Cain would be premeditated *murder*, which even today is considered a much more severe crime.

Answer (score 3):

Why does the punishment of him who kills Cain seem more severe in Genesis 4:15?

God wanted to nip the fast multiplication of murders in the bud.

Calvin's Commentary on the Bible

> But this sentence ought to be read continuously, thus, ‘Whosoever killeth Cain, shall on this account, be punished sevenfold.’ And the causal particle לכן (lekon,) indicates that God would take care to prevent any one from easily breaking in upon him to destroy him; not because God would institute a privilege in favor of the murderer, or would hearken to his prayers but because he would consult for posterity, in order to the **preservation of human life**. The order of nature had been awfully violated; what might be expected to happen in future, when the wickedness and audacity of man should increase, unless the fury of others had been **restrained** by a violent hand? For we know what pestilent and deadly poison Satan presents to us in evil examples, if a remedy be not speedily applied. Therefore, the Lord declares, if any will imitate Cain, not only shall they have no excuse in his example, but shall be more grievously tormented; because they ought, in his person, to perceive how detestable is their wickedness in the sight of God. Wherefore, they are greatly deceived who suppose that the anger of God is mitigated when men can plead custom as an excuse for sinning; whereas it is from that cause the more inflamed.

God wanted to be in control instead of men.

> Deuteronomy 32:35
> It is mine to avenge; I will repay.

Keil & Delitzsch Commentary on the Old Testament

> God granted him continuance of life, not because banishment from the place of God's presence was the greatest possible punishment, or because the preservation of the human race required at that time that the lives of individuals should be spared, - for God afterwards destroyed the whole human race, with the exception of one family, - but partly because the tares were to grow with the wheat, and sin develop itself to its utmost extent, partly also because from the very first God determined to take punishment into His own hands, and protect human life from the passion and **wilfulness of human vengeance**.

Answer (score 0):

When Cain killed Abel, God had not formally decreed a law against murder or a punishment for committing that crime. Now, however, both the crime and the punishment were stipulated: "any who kills Cain will suffer vengeance seven times over."

To us moderns, the punishment indeed seems excessive. We are only humans, and “Vengeance is mine, I will repay, says the Lord.” (Rom. 12:19) Nevertheless, as humans, our inquiring minds have to wonder. In my case, I wonder if perhaps God was still working on perfecting a system of Justice that would not near completion until the revelation at Sinai.